# How can revisions/version control be implemented for web apps' data

Tags: version-control

I believe Wordpress stores multiple entries of posts as "revisions" but I think thats terribly inefficient use of space?

Is there a better way? I think [gitit](http://gitit.net/) is a Wiki that uses GIT for version control, but how is it done? eg. my application is in PHP and I must make it talk to GIT to commit and retrieve data?

So, what is a good way of implementing version control in web apps (eg. in a blog it might be the post content)

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify a level at which you want to have VCS. Just store two posts versions or remember each letter pressed/deleted as a separate revision?

Comment: @KromStern, I think I will first want to store 2 post versions, maybe good to just store the changes if possible. Otherwise storing 2 posts will be trival. Having a diff feature will be a useful addition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've recently implemented just such a system - which uses the concept of superseded records, together with a previous and current link. I did a considerable amount of research into how best to achieve this - in the end the model I arrived at is similar to the Wordpress (and other systems) - store the changes as a new record and use this.

Considering all of the options available, space is really the last concern for authored content such as posts - media files take up way more space and these can't be stored as deltas anyway.

In any case the way that Git works is virtually identical in that it stores the entire content for every revision except that it will eventually pack down into deltas (or when you ask it to).

[image: Git Storage Object graph]

Going back to 1990 we were using SCCS or RCS and sometimes with only 30mb of disk space free we really needed the version control to be efficient to avoid running out of storage.

Using deltas to save space is not really worth all of the associated aggravation given the average amount of available storage on modern  systems.  You could argue it's wasteful of space, however I'd argue that it is much more efficient in the long run to store things uncompressed in their original form

- it's faster
- it's easier to search through old versions
- it's quicker to view
- it's easier to jump into the middle of a set of changes without having to process a lot of deltas.
- it's a lot easier to implement because you don't have to write delta generation algorithms.

Also markup doesn't fare as well as plain text with deltas especially when editing with a wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 2):

Keep one table with the most recent version of the e.g. article.

When a new version is saved, move the current over in an archive table and put a version number on it while keeping the most recent version in the first table.

The archive table can have the property ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED (MySQL InnoDb example) to take up less space and it won't be a performance issue since it is rarely accessed. Yes, it is somewhat overhead  not to only store changesets but if you do some math you can keep a huge amount of revisions in almost no space as your articles are highly compressable text anyway.

In example, the source code of this entire page is 11Kb compressed. That gives you almost 100 versions on 1Mb. In comparison, normal articles are quite a bit smaller and may on average give you 500-1000 articles/versions on 1Mb. You can probbably afford that.